# Correct way of using an image resource in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, performance, xamarin, memory-management, out-of-memory

Currently, I'm setting backgrounds for buttons/backgrounds/textboxs/etc in the AXML using:

```
<ImageButton
    p1:id="@+id/physicsOption"
    p1:layout_column="0"
    p1:layout_columnSpan="1"
    p1:layout_columnWeight="1"
    p1:layout_row="0"
    p1:layout_rowSpan="1"
    p1:layout_rowWeight="1"
    p1:layout_height="50dp"
    p1:layout_width="50dp"
    p1:padding="10dp"
    p1:scaleType="fitXY"
    p1:background="@drawable/GreenButtonIcon"
    p1:src="@drawable/PhysicsIcon" />
```

For example.

And I have the image saved in my Resources/Drawable as you can see. But when I boot up my app, i'm using 280Mb+ and each new layout will add an additional 30 - 80Mb running out of memory. I know I can just allocate more memory, but that can't be the right solution. So, how can I decrease my memory footprint?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: I know of a dozen ways of setting source and backgrounds. But what are some good ways of decreasing my memory footprint?

Comment: 1)   `...I know I can just allocate more memory...`, No you can not. 2) Drawables should be sized based upon the device resolution, see https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html#TaskProvideAltBmp

Comment: Because the your image's size is too big, so your app gets OOM, you need resize your image before your app loads it to avoid OOM, this is the correct way to decrease your memory footprint, there is no way to decrease the memory directly. If you call `GC.Collect();`, it also can't work well, because you are using C# language, the power of memory management lies in the garbage collector, not application developer.